# SOAP authentication problems

Tags: web-services, authentication, soap, credentials, nusoap

Im having a bit of a headache with this one. Using NuSOAP.

The webservice has a function called LOGIN that accepts the parameters USER and PASSWORD. But all I keep getting is the same error (authentication rejected for 'null') no matter if I try to authenticate through setCredentials or by calling the function with the parameters. This is the code Ive been playing with,at the bottom youll find the response.

---

```
$client = new nusoap_client('http://user:pass@xx.xx.xx.xx:9999/service?wsdl', 'WSDL');

//tested including user and password
//$client = new nusoap_client('http://user:pass@xx.xx.xx.xx:9999/service?wsdl', 'WSDL');

//check if there were any instantiation errors, and if so stop execution with an error    message:
 $error = $client->getError();

 if ($error)
 {
   die("client construction error: {$error}\n");
 }

//authenticate to the service:

 $client->setCredentials('user', 'pass');

$param = array('user' => 'user',
           'password' => 'pass');

 $answer = $client->call('login', array('parameters' => $param), '', '', false, true);
```

---

### Constructor error

```
soapenv:Server: Auth rejected for 'null' (403)
```

### Fault

```
Array
(
    [faultcode] => soapenv:Server
    [faultstring] => Auth rejected for 'null' (403)
    [detail] => Array
        (
            [ChargingException] => Array
                (
                    [detail] => 
                    [message] => Auth rejected for 'null' (403)
                )
```

`)`

)